# Run Rails Rake task on Heroku Scheduler as detached to capture log output in Papertrail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku, rake, papertrail-app

A known problem with running Rails Rake tasks on Heroku is that they don't submit their logs to Papertrail since the one-off dynos push their output to the console by default.  This is solved by running your dyno in "detached" mode by using `heroku run:detached rake your:task`.  Unfortunately, the Heroku Scheduler appears to automatically run tasks as normal instead of in detached mode so these logs are lost.

How can you make the scheduler run a task in "detached" mode so these weekly/daily/hourly tasks get their logs captured by Papertrail as expected?

Comment: +1 I would love something like this. With Jenkins and the like, you can view the log output for past runs. If available, I would use an add on to allow this.

Comment: If you have a worker dyno, you could encapsulate the current task code into a job and have the rake task enqueue that job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sidekiq, this gem will help you run any processes with schedule, and inside in your sidekiq you can run rake tasks!

> https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq

Example:

```
class MySidekiqTask
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    application_name = Rails.application.class.parent_name
    application = Object.const_get(application_name)
    application::Application.load_tasks
    Rake::Task['db:migrate'].invoke
  end
end
```

Good instruction how setup Sidekiq in Heroku server

> https://itnext.io/sidekiq-overview-and-how-to-deploy-it-to-heroku-b8811fea9347